# How to do Depth First Search on a graph that has no arrows?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I got this question for my homework and I am wondering if the answer is 
4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 9, 13, 7, 6, 10, 15, 11, 14, 8, 12, 16.

[image]

I got this

[image]

from that diagram , its based on Breadth First Search and I thought I can apply Depth First Search on it, is it right?

Comment: Hint: the first error in your answer is at `9`.

Comment: is my binary tree correct to apply depth first search?

Comment: In the binary tree why there is no edge between node 5 and 6 as in the graph of the homework question ?

Comment: Btw, a graph with no arrows is an undirected graph.

Comment: The key is in "Assume that vertices are listed in increasing order" so when you start at  4 (dfs) you first go to 3 (smallest), from 3 you go to 2 > 1 > 5  > 6 .....

Answer (score 0):

If you are exploring a graph using depth first search and edges are stored in an ascending-ordered adjacency list for each vertex, the next vertex you explore will always be the smallest vertex of the unexplored neighbors.

When starting with vertex 4, the adjacency list representation of the edges of vertex 4 will be [3, 8]. Assuming the depth first search discovers the next vertex by exploring the first vertex stored in the adjacency list, the vertex 3 will be the next one that is discovered.

Applying this through the rest of the problem, we can see that when you encountered the vertex 5 with adjacency list [1, 6, 9], you correctly skipped the vertex 1 because it was already explored. However, you incorrectly continued with vertex 9 from here instead of continuing with vertex 6.

The correct depth first search traversal with these constraints is:
4-3-2-1-5-6-7-8-12-11-14-10-9-13-15-16

Fixing this error should correct your problems with depth first search in this case. Try it starting at different vertices other than vertex 4 if you still need more practice. Good luck.